# Why do i get brut.androlib.AndrolibException-error while building apk-file with apktool?

Tags: apk, apktool

I downloaded some app from Google PlayStore and dissasabled it with:

```
$ apktool d my-app

I: Using Apktool 2.5.0 on my-app.apk
I: Loading resource table...
I: Decoding AndroidManifest.xml with resources...
I: Loading resource table from file: C:\Users\kreis\AppData\Local\apktool\framework\1.apk
I: Regular manifest package...
I: Decoding file-resources...
I: Decoding values */* XMLs...
I: Baksmaling classes.dex...
I: Baksmaling classes2.dex...
I: Baksmaling classes3.dex...
I: Copying assets and libs...
I: Copying unknown files...
I: Copying original files...
I: Copying META-INF/services directory
```

Now without any modification i want to compile it to apk-file and i become the same error each time:

```
$ apktool b jodel -o out.apk
I: Using Apktool 2.5.0
...
...
W: brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = 1): [C:\Users\kreis\AppData\Local\Temp\brut_util_Jar_71166972874490660111854333778234451644.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --version-code, 0000100, --version-name, 12.11.0, --no-version-vectors, -F, C:\Users\kreis\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOLsomecode3.tmp, -e, C:\Users\kreis\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOLsomecode.tmp, -0, arsc, -I, C:\Users\kreis\AppData\Local\apktool\framework\1.apk, -S, C:\Users\kreis\Downloads\my-app\res, -M, C:\Users\kreis\Downloads\my-app\AndroidManifest.xml]
```

I tried following:

1. Another versions: 2.3.0, 2.2.0 etc.
2. Adding -r and -s options
3. Any other alternatives to apktool: it still not working

I appreciate any help!